# How to define vFunctionCall in map in c++

Tags: c++, function, dictionary

How to define vFunctionCall in map?

It is right syntax?

```
typedef void(*vFunctionCall)(CommandStruct *cs);
static std::map< Command, vFunctionCall > Functions = {
    { e_testing, test},
    { e_echo, to_do }
};
```

Where:

```
struct CommandStruct {
     //some variables
}

enum Command {
     //some enums
}

void test(CommandStruct * cs);

void to_do(CommandStruct * cs);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it? How did it work? How didn't it work? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, it working nice but I dont know how to call function.

Comment: You have used a `std::map` before? What makes you think this will be much different?

Comment: It should work by using : `my_map[CMD_1] = &to_do;` to add the function to the map, and then call the function with `(*my_map[CMD_1])(cs)`.  
EDIT: Another advice, I would advise against unsing an `enum` in a map key type because maps behave differently depending on key type, so you should control exactly what type is used in the map (like `int` or even `int32_t`...). You'll also end up with iterators which are pointers to `std::pair<K,V>`, and it's a bad idea to point to an `enum`.